# No way to perform some asynchronous mongoose query operations on my collection

Tags: mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

My problem is that I cannot paginate my application without making adjustments on model or on controller. To paginate I need to perform sort-skip-limit operations which are related to Mongoose collections. `User.findById()` function returns only one value, then it is impossible to chain these operations after it. I need to perform the operations as a whole, what can I do?

I tried to perform on the new array that I pushed every user in it but the mongoose operations don't work on it.

```
Camp.findById(req.params.campId, async (err, camp) => {
        if(err) return res.redirect('/admin/camps');
        const resPerPage = 3;
        const page = req.query.page || 1;     
        const usersList = camp.usersList;
        let users = [];
        for(var userId of usersList) {
            const user = await User.findById(userId);
            //I want to perform .sort({follower: -1}).skip(resPerPage*(page-1)).limit(resPerPage)
            if(!user) return res.redirect('/admin/camps');
            users.push(user);
        };
```

Expected output: All users sorted by the number of followers

Actual output: All users regardless of the number of followers

Comment: Can you show the schema definitions for `Camp` and `User` models?

Comment: ````const CampSchema = new Schema({
    usersList: {
        type: Array,
        default: []
    },
})```` \n

Comment: If you have the `usersList` field set to an array of `ObjectIds` with a ref option that tells Mongoose which model to use during population i.e `const CampSchema = new Schema({ usersList: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]
});` you can run your query as `Camp.findById(req.params.campId)
  .populate({path: 'usersList', options: { sort: [['follower', 'desc']] }})`

Comment: It was very helpful, thanks but I don't have any idea how the code as a whole would look like?